# In Debian, is there a list of packages with dead parent project?

Tags: debian, package-management, packaging, deb

I have been looking (in https://db.debian.org/machines.cgi) for a service or list of Debian packages without upstream (parent project).

Because I think there are a lot of deb packages which are alive in Debian but are dead outside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Ultimate Debian Database](https://wiki.debian.org/UltimateDebianDatabase) has [an upstream version query](https://udd.debian.org/cgi-bin/upstream-status.json.cgi) which you can use to list all packages who either don’t have a watch file (to track upstream releases) or whose watch file results in an empty value (because upstream has gone, or an error occurred):

```
curl https://udd.debian.org/cgi-bin/upstream-status.json.cgi |
jq '.[] | select(.["upstream-version"] == null) | .package'
```

This doesn’t quite answer your question, since it won’t find packages which do track upstream releases, but where upstream releases are unlikely to ever occur again (for example, [`fyre`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/fyre), which I know has been abandoned for a long time). It will also find packages which are themselves unmaintained (they have an obsolete watch file, regardless of upstream’s status). But I think that this is the best you’ll get in an automated fashion.